# No cursor in psycopg2

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2, psql

There's no cursor in `psycopg2`. I used `pycharm` to install the library but I keep getting this same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
posts = forumdb.GetAllPosts()
File "/vagrant/forum/forumdb.py", line 13, in GetAllPosts
c = db.cursor()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: How do we know what kind of object your `db` variable  is ? It's kind of important.. Please create yourself a small but 100% complete example that you can share with us.

Comment: def GetAllPosts():
    db = psycopg2.connect('dbname=forum')
    c = db.cursor()